# Calculating the number of chords in a polygon

Tags: geometry

Does anyone know a general formula for calculating the number of chords in a polygon?

[image]

Comment: Is the polygon convex? If not, do we need to exclude chords that lie outside the polygon? That would make the problem harder.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

We know, $n$ sided polygon has $n$ vertices where integer $n\ge3$

Number of lines formed by $n$ points $=\binom n2, $ as each lines needs exactly $2$ points

Among them, $n$ is the number of sides

Comment: Putting **lab bhattacharjee**s and **user84413**'s answers together, we have the formula/identity $ \ n \cdot (n-3) \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \binom n2 - n \ . $

Comment: Can You help me understanding how do you arrive to this solution and how to use this identity?

Comment: I arrive to this solution. If c is the number of chords, l the number of sides of a polygon and n the number of chords for each point (vertices). Then we can suppose that c=(l(n))/2. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Each vertex can be joined to n-3 vertices to form a diagonal (or chord),
since the vertex cannot be joined to itself or the two adjacent vertices; and we do not care in which order the endpoints of the diagonal are chosen.